# errors are not displaying in PHP script

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have tried with these code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

ini_set("display_startup_errors","on");
ini_set("track_errors","on");
ini_set("error_reporting","E_ALL^E_NOTICE");
```

But still errors are not appearing on my script.It just displaying only blank white screen when any error occur.Please guide me.

Comment: can you post the code? sometimes your statements might have `@` in front of them which tells PHP to suppress the errors?

Comment: Check the source (view-source) of the blank page. What does it show?

Comment: it is real code,i not used @ sign anywhere

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your provider has set PHP errors not to be output, but logged internally. I have experienced this before. In that case, a [custom error handler](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler) may help you. Before, though, make sure you have no @s in front of any statements and [log_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) is on. Also run a  `phpinfo()` to double-check whether all reporting settings are activated.

Also, a completely blank page could be a structural parse error. Check with a simple error-inducing statement like

```
ecxho("hello world");
```

first.

Comment: i not used @ sign .Can you tell how custom error handler can be used here.

Comment: Take the myErrorHandler() example in the documentation I linked to. That should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

?

Comment: +1 error_reporting is one thing, displaying errors to the standard output is another.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on your own server? Or shared hosting etc? It's likely that error reporting is turned off at the server level. (The reason is usually 'security' but I don't see how it's really a security issue.)

Either edit your server config (`php.ini`) if you have access to it, or contact your host. They may be able to provide access to error logs.

Comment: I think the rationale is that public-facing errors can reveal details about the server's filesystem and the framework (if any) that the site uses. This can give someone a leg-up in finding exploits and vulnerabilities in the site or server. With shared hosting, a single vulnerable site can compromise every site on the server.

Comment: True - I guess I'm looking at it from a "purist" POV in the sense that if there's a security hole, it still exists whether you reveal details about the filesystem or not. Attackers could easily try exploits for all the popular frameworks/software regardless.